# Pairing a gsub function and text file for corpus cleaning

Tags: r, text, text-files, gsub, data-cleaning

I have a large sample of tweets that I  am trying to clean up before I analyze them. I have the tweets in a dataframe where each cell has the contents of one tweet (e.g. "i love san francisco" and "proud member of the air force"). However, there are some words in each bio that should be combined when I analyze the text in a network visualization. I want to also combine common two-word phrases (e.g. "new york", "san francisco", and "air force"). I have already compiled the list of terms that need to be combined, and have used `gsub` to combine a few of them with this line of code:

```
twitterdata_cleaning$bio = gsub('air force','airforce',twitterdata_cleaning$bio)
```

The line of code above turns `"proud member of the air force"` into `"proud member of the airforce"`. I have been able to successfully do this with dozens of two-word phrases.

However, I have hundreds of two-word phrases in the bios, and I want to keep a better track of them, so I've moved all of these terms into two columns in an excel file. I would like to find a way to use the above formula on a txt or excel file, that identifies terms in the dataframe that look like those in the first column of the txt file and changes the words to look like those in the second column of the txt file.

For example, I have xlsx and txt files that look like this:

```
    **column1**               **column2*
   san francisco              sanfrancisco
     new york                   newyork
     las vegas                  lasvegas
     san diego                  sandiego
   new hampshire              newhampshire
      good bye                   goodbye
      air force                  airforce
     video game                 videogame
    high school                  school
    middle school                school
    elementary school            school
```

I would like to use the `gsub` command in a formula that searches the dataframe for all the terms in `column 1` and terms them into the terms in `column 2` using something like this:

```
twitterdata_df$tweet = gsub('textfile$column1','textfile$columnb',twitterdata_df$tweet)
```

to get something like this in the cells:

```
i love sanfrancisco
can not wait to go to newyork
what happens in lasvegas stays there
at the beach in sandiego
can beat the autumn leave in newhampshire
so done with all the drama goodbye
proud member of the airforce
love this videogame so much
playing at the school tonight 
so sick of school
school was the best and i miss it
```

Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are either looking for the `adist` function or an equivalent eg vectorized agrep etc. Your problem statement is unclear. We are unable to tell exactly what you have and what you want to obtain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, but I found out how to do it. I decided to use a loop, which went into my my table of two columns, and searched for each set of terms in the first column and replaced them with the word in the second column.

```
 for(i in 1:nrow(compoundterms)) {
            twitterdata_dfg$tweet = gsub(compoundterms[i,1],compoundterms[i,2],twitterdata_df$tweet)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

### Generalized Solution

You can feed in a named vector to `str_replace_all()` from package `stringr` to accomplish this. In my example `df` has a column with `old` values to be replaced by `new` values. This I assume is what you mean by having an Excel file to track them.

```
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(old = c("five", "six", "seven"),
                 new = as.character(5:7),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

text <- c("I am a vector with numbers six and other text five",
          "another vector seven six text five")

str_replace_all(text, setNames(df$new, df$old))
```

Result:

```
[1] "I am a vector with numbers 6 and other text 5" "another vector 7 6 text 5"
```

---

#### Specific Example

**Data**

Read in the text file with the replacements.

```
textfile <- read.csv(textConnection("column1,column2
san francisco,sanfrancisco
new york,newyork
las vegas,lasvegas
san diego,sandiego
new hampshire,newhampshire
good bye,goodbye
air force,airforce
video game,videogame
high school,school
middle school,school
elementary school,school"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Load a data frame with tweets in the column `tweet`.

```
twitterdata_df <- data.frame(id = 1:11)
twitterdata_df$tweet <- c("i love san francisco",
                          "can not wait to go to new york",
                          "what happens in las vegas stays there",
                          "at the beach in san diego",
                          "can beat the autumn leave in new hampshire",
                          "so done with all the drama goodbye",
                          "proud member of the air force",
                          "love this video game so much",
                          "playing at the high school tonight",
                          "so sick of middle school",
                          "elementary school was the best and i miss it")
```

**Replace**

```
twitterdata_df$tweet2 <- str_replace_all(twitterdata_df$tweet, setNames(textfile$column2, textfile$column1))
```

**Result**

As you can see, the replacements were made in `tweet2`.

```
   id                                        tweet                                    tweet2
1   1                         i love san francisco                       i love sanfrancisco
2   2               can not wait to go to new york             can not wait to go to newyork
3   3        what happens in las vegas stays there      what happens in lasvegas stays there
4   4                    at the beach in san diego                  at the beach in sandiego
5   5   can beat the autumn leave in new hampshire can beat the autumn leave in newhampshire
6   6           so done with all the drama goodbye        so done with all the drama goodbye
7   7                proud member of the air force              proud member of the airforce
8   8                 love this video game so much               love this videogame so much
9   9           playing at the high school tonight             playing at the school tonight
10 10                     so sick of middle school                         so sick of school
11 11 elementary school was the best and i miss it         school was the best and i miss it
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, but when I try to run the str_replace_all funciton with my dataframe I get and error:  Error in UseMethod("type") : 
  no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: Your data is reading in and converting the text to factors. That is why I have the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` part in. What function are you using to read in your data? There is usually a similar option. Or, just convert the columns after the fact using `as.character()`.

Comment: Adam, thanks. I got the stringsAsFactors to work, but the code still wasn't working. I realized that I didn't give enough information, such as the fact the terms were sharing cells with other words, so the code your provided didn't work. I've since updated my original post with more specific information about what I need to to. Thank you though for helping me. I appreciate it.

Comment: I guess now I am a bit confused. Which exact is not working? That code should work on a vector of inputs, and return a vector back with the replacement made. By cells, do you mean the set of old/new terms to replace (e.g., "new york" and "newyork"), or each element of the `twitterdata_df$tweet` vector?

Comment: Hey Adam, sorry for the delayed response! I figured it out. I'll post what I did as an answer.